# Unbuffered/Buffered Socket Reading

Tags: c, sockets, io

I am trying to write echo server in C with following I/O functions. https://gist.github.com/demirbey05/bff227d6e8bc0b4871889e227cf72fa0

As you can understand from the code file above, there are buffered and unbuffered I/O functions.

My server and client codes are shown below respectively :

```
void echo(int connfd){
    size_t n;
    char buf[1024];
    rio_t rio;

    rio_readinitb(&rio,connfd);
    while((n = rio_readlineb(&rio,buf,1024)) != 0){
        printf("server received %d bytes\n", (int)n);
        rio_writen(connfd, buf, n);
    }
}


int main(int argc,char **args) {

    if(argc < 2 ){
        fprintf(stderr,"usage %s <port_name>",args[0]);
        exit(0);
    }

    int listenfd,connfd;
    char buf[1024] ,port[1024];
    struct sockaddr_storage clientaddr;
    socklen_t socksize;
    listenfd =  open_listenfd(args[1]);


    while (1) {
        socksize = sizeof(struct sockaddr_storage);
        connfd = accept(listenfd,(SA *) &clientaddr,&socksize);
        getnameinfo(&clientaddr,socksize,buf,1024,port,1024,0);
        printf("Connected to (%s:%s)\n",buf,port);
        echo(connfd);
        close(connfd);
    }
    exit(0);


}
```

```
int main(int argc,char **args){

    if(argc < 3){
        fprintf(stderr,"usage %s <hostname> <portname>",args[0]);
        exit(0);
    }

    int clientfd;
    rio_t rio;
    char buf[1024],echo[1024];

    clientfd = open_clientfd(args[1],args[2]);
    rio_readinitb(&rio,clientfd);

    while(fgets(buf,1024,stdin) != NULL){
        fprintf(stdout,"okan");
        rio_writen(clientfd,buf, strlen(buf));
        rio_readlineb(&rio,echo,1024);
        printf("The echoed message is : %s",echo);
    }
    exit(0);

}
```

The client and server use buffered I/O for data transmission. The system is working properly. Then I decided to change echo to an unbuffered version :

```
void echo(int connfd){
    size_t n;
    char buf[1024];
    rio_t rio;

 
    while((n = rio_readn(connfd,buf,1024)) != 0){
        printf("server received %d bytes\n", (int)n);
        rio_writen(connfd, buf, n);
    }
}
```

Then, the code started to not work properly. The client can't send data(I put printf in a while loop of the client). I couldn't understand why the system fell.

Comment: You've got a deadlock. `rio_readn()` doesn't return until it reads N bytes or EOF. The client isn't sending 1024 bytes before it tries to read the reply, and doesn't close the connection.

Comment: The first version works because `rio_readlineb()` returns when it gets to a newline.

Comment: The same thing isn't required for the buffered version? At the end buffered version uses a read syscall.

Comment: As I said, the buffered version doesn't try to read all N bytes. It returns when it gets to the newline at the end of each line.

Comment: You'll run into the same problem with `rio_readlineb()` if the data doesn't contain any newlines. But that doesn't happen because you're using `fgets()` in the client.

Comment: I changed to rio_readn(connfd,buf,5). I was supposed to read 5 characters, but still same thing is happening

Comment: I think Fgets is not returning. I don't understand the reason. I put printf after fgets check in while loop for logging and printf did not write.

Comment: @H.Okan If you're waiting for output from `printf()`, are you aware that `stdout` is buffered and usually doesn't write anything until it hits a newline unless you call `fflush( stdout );`?

Comment: Because it's never getting past `rio_readlineb()`, because the server is still stuck in  `rio_readn()` and never sending a reply.